# Is there an API that can allow me to send command to Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm setting up a smart home server in my house, and want to develop an app on iPad to communicate with other smart home devices.  But I don't want to use microphone, I just want to click a button on my App, and it will send command to Google Assistant

I am a beginner on Google Actions, I don't know how to start easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Assistant has two client libraries, in [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview) and [Java / Kotlin](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/java/overview), that help developers build actions for the Google Assistant. You can also review the [specific resources available for Smart Home projects](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/).

Once you have an idea of what you want to develop, Google has published [a series of Codelabs](https://developers.google.com/actions/codelabs/) to help you start writing code.

Good luck!